# Count elements and output in a pseudo-element

Tags: javascript, css, count, pseudo-element

I have a div with class name 'vc_tta-panels'. Within this div are several div's with class name 'vc_tta-panel'. I want to count the div's in the vc_tta-panels div. How can I do this? 
And how can I show the count result on a different page in a li pseudo-element with class name 'menu-item-4331::after' using content: ""; in css?

```
<div class="vc_tta-panels">
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To count child divs only:

```
var divsNumber = $('.vc_tta-panels > div').length;
```

But if you want all divs, children and children of children ....

```
var divsNumber = $('.vc_tta-panels div').length;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divsNumber = $('.vc_tta-panels > div').length;
    console.log('Numbers: ' + divsNumber);
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
 
 <div class="vc_tta-panels">
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel"></div>
</div>
```

To send it to another page you can use Query String:

```
 var divsNumber = $('.vc_tta-panels > div').length;
 window.location.href = ANOTHERPAGE.html?number=divsNumber;
```

And in another page get this number:

```
<script>
    (function ($)
    {
        $.QueryString = (function (a)
        {
            if (a == "") return {};
            var b = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            {
                var p = a[i].split('=');
                if (p.length != 2) continue;
                b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            return b;
        })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
    })(jQuery);
    var num = $.QueryString["number "];
    $('.menu-item-4331').after().css('content', num);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count the div's in the vc_tta-panels div. How can I do this?

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the elements. Like this:

```
var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.vc_tta-panels > .vc_tta-panel');
```

This shall return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (which is a collection not an array). Use its `length` property to get the number of elements selected. Like this:

```
var count = panels.length;
```

> And how can I show the count result on a different page in a li
>   pseudo-element with class name 'menu-item-4331::after' using content:
>   ""; in css?

Once you have the result on your other page (via server-side), you may cache those in [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on your relevant `li`. Use those `data-` attributes for the `content` in the pseudo-element CSS. Like this:

Markup in Page 2:

```
<ul class="page2">
  <li data-count="0">Menu option one</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.page2 li::after {
  content: attr(data-count); 
}
```

---

Here is a small snippet putting everything together:

```js
// One page 1
var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.vc_tta-panels > .vc_tta-panel'), 
  count = panels.length;

// Send the count to another page via server-side
// Once on the page 2...

var menuoptions = document.querySelectorAll('ul.page2 li');
// Add the count to pseudo-element of first option..
menuoptions[0].dataset.count = count;
```

```css
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
ul.page2 li::after {
 content: attr(data-count); 
 text-align: center; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px;
 display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin-left: 8px;
 width: 16px; height: 16px;
 color: #fff; background-color: #e33; border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3>On page 1</h3>
<div class="vc_tta-panels">
  <div class="vc_tta-panel">panel 1</div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel">panel 2</div>
  <div class="vc_tta-panel">panel 3</div>
</div>
<hr />
<h3>On page 2</h3>
<ul class="page2">
 <li data-count="0">Menu option one</li>
 <li data-count="0">Menu option two</li>
</ul>
```